# LinQ to XML, selecting a node with 2 levels of search criteria

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm struggling to select a node two levels deep with a search criteria which I want to modify, what am I doing wrong?
I guess I'm essentially looking for a way to make a second "Where" level under the first query to select a specific sub-level.

XML:

```
    <Model IDCode="ed385480-8905-4ddb-82b5-0eb9415b7676" Code="IGC">
    <Locations>
       <Location Type="Hub" Country="US" Office="NY" Contact="Frank"></Location>
       <Location Type="Satellite" Country="US" Office="LA" Contact="Sinatra"></Location>
    <Locations>
    </Model>
    <Model IDCode="ed385480-8905-4ddb-82b5-0eb9415b7676" Code="ABC">
    <Locations>
      <Location Type="Hub" Country="US" Office="NY" Contact="James"></Location>
      <Location Type="Satellite" Country="US" Office="LA" Contact="Franco"></Location>
    </Locations>
    </Model>
```

And the code used;

```
    var locations= from IDCode in xdocConfig.Elements("Model")
                where IDCode != null && (IDCode.Attribute("IDCode").Value == Current.IDCode)
        select IDCode.Element("Locations");

        foreach (var location in locations)
        {
            if (location.Attribute("Office").Value == "LA")
            {
                location.SetAttributeValue("Office", "new value");
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: Use : location.SetAttributeValue("Office", "new value");

Comment: Indeed a better way to get there, I'll update that, thank you. 
Reaching the node for updating is my problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Note : Both Models have same IDCode.  You can use Xml Linq with a dictionary

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, XElement>> dict = doc.Descendants("Model")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("Code"), y => y.Descendants("Location")
                    .GroupBy(a => (string)a.Attribute("Office"), b => b)
                    .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, b => b.FirstOrDefault()))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            Dictionary<string, XElement> igc = dict["IGC"];
            XElement la = igc["LA"];
            la.SetAttributeValue("Office", "NY");

        }
    }
}
```